# silex routes not working

Tags: php, routes, openshift, silex

I;m having a problem with my routing on a silex app I am deploying.
I have successfully deployed the app using OpenShift you can see the site [here](http://f2f-face2face.rhcloud.com/).
The problem is when I try to go to any page except the home page I get a 404 error that reads

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /login was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at f2f-face2face.rhcloud.com Port 80

now this leads me to believe that my app.php file has something wrong with it, or the server is trying to find files that are in another location. When I use the rhc "tail" logs tool i get:

`Mon Nov 02 19:28:46 2015] [error] [client 127.11.58.129] File does not exist: /var/lib/openshift/5637e0bd89f5cf939b00000e/app-root/runtime/repo/web/login, referer: http://f2f-face2face.rhcloud.com/
98.246.242.195 - - [02/Nov/2015:19:28:46 -0500] "GET /login? HTTP/1.1" 404 295 "http://f2f-face2face.rhcloud.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"`

my app.php file looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__."/../vendor/autoload.php";
require_once __DIR__."/../src/User.php";
require_once __DIR__."/../src/Place.php";

$app = new Silex\Application();

// $app['debug']=true;

define('DB_HOST', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'));
define('DB_PORT',getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT'));
define('DB_USER',getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'));
define('DB_PASS',getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'));
define('DB_NAME',getenv('OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME'));


$server = 'mysql:dbname='.DB_NAME.';host='.DB_HOST.';port='.DB_PORT;;
$username = 'MYUSERNAMEATOPENSHIFT';
$password = 'MYPASSWORDATOPENSHIFT';
$DB = new PDO($server, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/../views'
));

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();

//home page (sign up page)
$app->get("/", function() use($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('home.html.twig');
});

//after log off
$app->get("/logoff/{id}", function($id) use($app) {
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->logOut();
    return $app['twig']->render('home.html.twig');
});

//list of users page
    //after sign up
$app->post("/signup", function() use($app) {
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $retype_password = $_POST['retype_password'];
    $latitude = 45.516231;
    $longitude = -122.682519;
    $signed_in = true;

    $user = new User($user_name, $password, $longitude, $latitude, $signed_in, $id=null);
    $user->save();

    return $app['twig']->render('users.html.twig', array('user' => $user, 'avialable_users' => $user->findUsersNear(), 'requests' => $user->findMeetupRequests()));
});

//log in page
$app->get("/login", function() use($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('login.html.twig');
});

$app->get("/logged_on", function() use ($app) {
    $user_name = $_GET['username'];
    $user = User::findByUserName($user_name);
    $user_logged = $user->logIn($user_name, $_GET['password']);
    if($user_logged == "Wrong Password") {
        return $app['twig']->render('login.html.twig');
    } else {
        return $app['twig']->render('users.html.twig', array('user' => $user_logged, 'avialable_users' => $user->findUsersNear(), 'requests' => $user->findMeetupRequests()));
    }
});

$app->post("/request_meetup", function() use ($app) {
    $user1 = User::find($_POST['user1_id']);
    $user2 = User::find($_POST['user2_id']);
    $location = Place::setMeetupLocation($user1, $user2);
    $user1->addMeetUpRequest($user2->getId(), $location->getId());

    return $app['twig']->render('waiting_to_confirm.html.twig', array('user1_id' => $user1->getId(), 'user2_id' => $user2->getId()));
});

//waiting for request respond page
$app->get("/wait_for_confirmation", function() use ($app) {
    $user1 = User::find($_GET['user1_id']);
    $user2 = User::find($_GET['user2_id']);

    if(($user1->hasUserTwoConfirmed($user2->getId())) == NULL) {
        return $app['twig']->render('waiting_to_confirm.html.twig', array('user1_id' => $user1->getId(), 'user2_id' => $user2->getId()));
    } else {
        if(($user1->hasUserTwoConfirmed($user2->getId()))) {
            $location = Place::getMeetUpLocation($user1->getId(), $user2->getId());
            return $app['twig']->render('confirmed_user1.html.twig', array('user_to_meet' => $user2, 'user' => $user1, 'location' => $location));
        } else {
            return $app['twig']->render('rejected.html.twig', array('user' => $user1, 'user_to_meet' => $user2));
        }
    }
});
$app->post("/confirm_request", function() use ($app) {
    $user1 = User::find($_POST['user1_id']);
    $user2 = User::find($_POST['user2_id']);

    $user1->confirmMeetupRequest($user2->getId());
    $location = Place::getMeetUpLocation($user2->getId(), $user1->getId());
    return $app['twig']->render('confirmed_user2.html.twig', array('user_to_meet' => $user2, 'user' => $user1, 'location' => $location));
});

$app->post("/reject_request", function() use ($app) {
    $user1 = User::find($_POST['user1_id']);
    $user2 = User::find($_POST['user2_id']);

    $user1->rejectMeetupRequest($user2->getId());
    return $app['twig']->render('users.html.twig', array('user' => $user1, 'avialable_users' => $user1->findUsersNear(), 'requests' => $user1->findMeetupRequests()));
});

$app->post("/user1_confirm_meet", function() use ($app) {
    $user1 = User::find($_POST['user1_id']);
    $user2 = User::find($_POST['user2_id']);
    $user1->confirmMeetUserOne($user2->getId(), true);
    return $app['twig']->render('confirmation.html.twig', array('user' => $user1));
});

$app->post("/user2_confirm_meet", function() use ($app) {
    $user1 = User::find($_POST['user1_id']);
    $user2 = User::find($_POST['user2_id']);
    $user1->confirmMeetUserTwo($user2->getId(), true);
    return $app['twig']->render('confirmation.html.twig', array('user' => $user1));
});

$app->post("/user1_deny_meet", function() use ($app) {
    $user1 = User::find($_POST['user1_id']);
    $user2 = User::find($_POST['user2_id']);
    $user1->confirmMeetUserOne($user2->getId(), false);
    return $app['twig']->render('deny.html.twig', array('user' => $user1));
});

$app->post("/user2_deny_meet", function() use ($app) {
    $user1 = User::find($_POST['user1_id']);
    $user2 = User::find($_POST['user2_id']);
    $user1->confirmMeetUserTwo($user2->getId(), false);
    return $app['twig']->render('deny.html.twig', array('user' => $user1));
});

$app->get("go_home", function() use ($app) {
    $user = User::find($_GET['user1_id']);
    return $app['twig']->render('users.html.twig', array('user' => $user, 'avialable_users' => $user->findUsersNear(), 'requests' => $user->findMeetupRequests()));
});
return $app;
```

?>
Its a long block of code but all you really need to see in there is that I am using linkes like /login or /signup to route to different pages.

Edit: also I think I may need a .htaccess file, but I'm also not sure and having trouble finding what actually needs to go into that file.

I've been stumped on this one all day and I would really appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in the [docs](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html#apache):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /path/to/app
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

You basically need to redirect all requests to non-existing files to your front controller.

Comment: awesome. so I just put that file right as you show it there into my web folder (my document root) and everything seems to work. Thanks a lot it was hard for me to track down how that all worked!